# Tshark TCP hex flags to text labels

Tags: tcp, tshark, hexdump

First question may take care of this. When capturing in tshark using fields, like "-e tcp.flags", is there a way to have the output the flag label, like "FIN", instead of "0x1"? I've done a few searches through documentation. Probably right under my nose.

If not, then I need a function in my data pipeline to convert the hex into the labels. I thought about having a dictionary like "{'0x1':'FIN'}" and map it, but I'm not sure of all the flag combos that might appear.

So I am taking the hex string, converting it to an integer, then to a binary string. I turn that into a list "[0,0,0,0,0,1]" and use that like a filter against a label list like "[u, a, p, r, s, f]" that returns any labels joined, like "f" or "a_s". Using Python.
Is this function necessary? Is there a more efficient/ elegant way to convert the hex to labels?

Answer (score 2):

Normally I would suggest using `-e tcp.flags.str`, but this doesn't display properly for me at least running on Windows 10 w/TShark (Wireshark) 3.3.0 (v3.3.0rc0-1433-gcac1426dd6b2).  For example, here's what I get for what should be a "SYN" indication only:

```
tshark.exe -r tcpfile.pcap -c 1 -T fields -e frame.number -e tcp.flags -e tcp.flags.str
1       0x00000002      A·A·A·A·A·A·A·A·A·A·SA·
```

You can try it on your system and maybe it'll display as intended (In Wireshark, it's displayed correctly as `··········S·`, so it may be a tshark bug or a problem with my shells - tried with both cmd and powershell.)  In any case, if it doesn't display properly for you on your system, you can try using the [tcp-flags-postdissector.lua](http://blog.didierstevens.com/2014/04/28/tcp-flags-for-wireshark/) dissector that Didier Stevens wrote, which was inspired by Snort and which I believe served as the inspiration for the Wireshark built-in `tcp.flags.str` field.  I personally preferred a '.' instead of '*' for flag bits that aren't set, so I tweaked the Lua dissector to behave that way.  Use it as is, or tweak it anyway you choose.  With the Lua dissector, I get the expected output:

```
tshark.exe -r tcpfile.pcap -c 1 -T fields -e frame.number -e tcp.flags tcpflags.flags
1       0x00000002      ........S.
```

Since the same incorrect string is displayed in both cmd and powershell, it looks like a tshark bug to me, so I filed [Wireshark Bug 16649](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16649).

Comment: Update: Bug 16649 has been fixed, but it hasn't been back-ported to any of the stable branches, although I'm not sure why not.  You may be able to download a recent automated installer from https://www.wireshark.org/download/automated/, but if there's not one available for your platform, then you'll either have to build Wireshark yourself, wait for the Wireshark 3.4.0 release to come out (Q3 2020 per https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LifeCycle), or request that this bug fix be back-ported in the Bug tracker or on the Wireshark developer mailing list: https://www.wireshark.org/lists/.